First ESXi server build using RAID
I am new to building an ESXi server and RAID in general and needed some assistance.
I have an HP Proliant DL360 server that needs ESXi installed with RAID configuration for redundancy. The server has 3 960GB SSDs and I need to figure out how it should be split up.
Does RAID need to be configured on the disks first before ESXi is installed? Or can I install ESXi first and then setup RAID 5 with the remaining partition of the OS drive and 2 other drives for the datastores?
Or does it make more sense to dedicate 1 entire 960GB SSD for the ESXi OS, and the remaining 2 in RAID 1 for the datastores?

RAID through software or hardware? What RAID configuration exactly? That determines the minimum number of disks you require. You probably don’t want to put ESXi on the same disks as your data storage.

through hardware using an HPE MR Gen10 Plus Controller. If I dont want to put ESXi on the same disks as my datastores, then the only option I have is to dedicate 1 entire 960GB SSD to my OS, and the remaining two drives configured as RAID 1 correct?

[Edit] your question to include those details

okay so i think my understanding of RAID was incorrect. I am currently in the MR storage administrator tool configuring the 3 drives for RAID 5. created an array and decided to split it up into 6 logical drives at 297GB each. Can I then use one of these logical drive spaces for my OS and the remainder for my datastores?

You really don’t want to RAID 5, 6 logical drives across 3 physical drives, that will cause you to be unable to lose any drive from a physical failure. Failure across a single logical partition failure won’t be isolated to a single logical partition in reality

Would my best option then be a single drive for the ESXi OS, and the other two in a RAID 1 mirror?

or what if i RAID 5 3 logical drives across 3 physical disks? would that be any better since installing esxi will partition one of the drives and the remaining free space from that drive can be used for the datastore?
